# Integrate API with Authorization Key Header in Swift

Tags: swift

I am having trouble integrating OwlBot dictionary API in my Swift app.

I use the following generic structure to integrate API into my app (it works with APIs without keys, only addition I did is `allHTTPHeaderFields`):

```
struct APIReader {
    func getJSON(urlString: String, completion: @escaping ([DictionaryWord]?) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
            "Authorization": "Token [My API key]"
        ]
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            guard let decodedData = try? decoder.decode([DictionaryWord].self, from: data) else {
                return
            }
            completion(decodedData)
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

When I call the function I pass the following parameters to the function:

```
apiReader.getJSON(urlString: "https://owlbot.info/api/v4/dictionary/bird")
```

It however doesn't produce any results, I can tell my `decodedData` is not produced as the last guard statement returns from the function.

My GET request works fine in Postman which makes it even weirder.

Comment: Can you add some traces / debug statements so we can see exactly what's happening?

Comment: Don't use `try?`. Use `do/catch` with `try`. Add `print(error)` inside the `catch`. Then you will know why the decoding is failing instead of ignoring the error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I save the token in KeyChain. Then I use an extension of URLRequest to get and set the authorization header.

In the following snippet, I have used Bearer token for authorization.

```
extension URLRequest {
    init(baseUrl: String, path: String) {
        let url = URL(baseUrl: baseUrl, path: path, params: params, method: method)
        let token = KeyChainPreference.shared.loadKeyChainString(forKey: KeyChainKey.authToken.rawValue)

        self.init(url: url)
        setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This line is unusual:

```
        "Authorization": "Token [My API key]"
```

In most systems, this would be (from [RFC 6750](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750)):

```
        "Authorization": "Bearer [My API key]"
```

Are you sure you're passing the right header? I would check the docs for your service. It's possible they're using a different specification.

Comment: I'm certain the syntax I'm using is correct, Postman works correctly and here's the email I've been provided along with the key:

curl --header "Authorization: Token [MyKey]"

Answer (score -1):

Try this syntax, which I use in my [Swift Demo App's Api Client class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios/blob/master/Source/Api/Client/ApiClient.swift):

```swift
request.addValue("Token \(myApiKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Also, I recommend an investment in receiving and reporting errors, since that will improve productivity. Maybe start by sending an incorrect API key in Postman, to understand the format of error responses, then [read the response details](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios/blob/master/Source/Plumbing/Errors/ErrorFactory.swift#L184) in your Swift code, from the `HTTPURLResponse` object.